# How to divide window into game and highscore bar

Tags: c++, window, sfml

I'm working on a game, Snake, in SFML. The game is almost finished, can move, can eat, can expand, can die and all that.

What I want now is a highscore bar over the "gamefield". I would want to know if there's someway I can divide the window in a arena and in a highscore bar.

For example the snake might be moving at posY: 0 px but that is in fact 100px of the window. This way I don't have to change all my code and make snake "die" when < 100 px. Is it posible to divide the window or is there another better way of doing this? I want something like this (just an example I made):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IBha.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you seperate your game objects from concerns like their position on the screen.  Instead, they should store what their position is on the playing field.  Then the playing field, knowing that it is positioned 100 pixels below the top of the render window, can draw the game objects, making the appropriate transformations.